# Alfresco 5.1 Community won't start

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, catalina

just all of the sudden, my alfresco won't start. i've tried all possible things i can do to check but to no avail. here is my [Catalina Log](http://pastebin.com/ewaVzfmp) and [Tomcat Log](http://pastebin.com/EVyrccK9). I've not made any configurations with the properties or sort. it was also running a few moment ago, alfresco is running on my local machine, Windows 8.1 with proper Java Runtimes.

Comment: It looks like there is an other app running on the same port, an other JVM maybe ? an old alfresco instance ?

Comment: currently, i only have a single instance of alfresco running on my local machine. i don't remember any other apps that might run on JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Younes is correct, the log shows that the Tomcat startup port, 8005, is already taken. This is a clear sign that you have more than one Tomcat running (or something else has grabbed that port).

Completely stop all Tomcats. Use your Windows Task Manager to make sure none are running. If you have to restart the machine to be sure, do that. Once you are sure no other Tomcats are running, try to restart.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows for how to find out what that other process is!

Comment: seems that it was the problem. i checked all accessed ports and 8005 was blocked by another program. i've uninstalled the said program for now and alfresco is back and working again. thank you Mr Potts